# CSS column count and transition - weird jump on Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm using CSS column count property to achieve 2 columns. When I have a button with hover animation - the first column button works fine but the 2nd column button give a weird jump on hover.

For container I'm using

```
column-count: 2;
```

for button its

```
transition: all ease-in .2s;
transform: translateX(0);
```

and button hover its

```
transform: translateX(10px);
```

I've made a little fiddle for demonstration. Its not working only in Chrome - weirdly.
http://jsfiddle.net/jp6vt97g/2/

Any Idea guys?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug in Chrome. CSS columns support on Chrome is still quite buggy.

Comment: I can see, wondering if there is any workaround..

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in Chrome when using `transform` inside columns. As a workaround, you can animate `margin-left` instead of `transform`.

```
.cta-txt {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all ease-in .2s;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.cta-txt:hover{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfgueg49/1/

Comment: @Hasanavi: [This indeed is a long unresolved bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177556#c13). Just adding a `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` to the `.cta-txt` will solve the problem. -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jp6vt97g/3/

Comment: @Abhitalks, Nice fix. Sadly, it works only on Chrome and not Safari.

Comment: Thanks @bumpy, Thats a nice workaround but I need to do it with transition way as margin is using for other purpose... Lets see if I can find any other solution

Comment: @Hasanavi What are you using margin for? You can also use the same principal with padding-left